# identical ros nodes

Tags: ros, nodes, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to launch a ROS node per ssh on a Ubuntu computer where the same node (different executable) is being launched at the same time (by a friend). I am doing this from a different user account, but both nodes are crashing when doing this. My question is: is it possible for us both to run the same node simultaneously without affecting each other?

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229033/identical-ros-nodes/) by [Satori](https://answers.ros.org/users/26265/satori/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes and no.

You can run the same node (i.e. even the same executable) multiple times, if you give them different names in `roslaunch` (check the [roslaunch syntax](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node)).

You cannot launch two nodes (does not matter if it is the same or another executable) with the same name

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Satori](https://answers.ros.org/users/26265/satori/) on 2016-03-14**:
OK, but if I have launch file which starts lots of other nodes as well, would this still work? or do I have to rename all other nodes as well?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-14**:
Yes; you'll have to rename every node, or push the whole launch file into a namespace.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-14**:
Be careful running multiple copies of the same node or set of nodes; if both use the same topics, you could end up with multiple nodes publishing on the same topic. Depending on what your subscribers on that topic do with the data, they could behave poorly.